# How to install radicale (CardDAV & CalDAV) on a headless RaspberryPi?

Tags: headless, pip

I want to install a server for CalDAV and CardDAV on my headless RaspberryPi and will use my answer below to make a guide which I will update as I go along. I had troubles installing pip for python3, using the browser to access a headless localhost and finding out the default login credentials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of this is from the Radicale installation instruction, but I had some troubles getting it right.

Also, this is a good practice for setting up a `systemd` service and using `htpasswd`. First, ssh into RPi, then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade radicale
sudo python3 -m radicale --config "" --storage-filesystem-folder=~/.var/lib/radicale/collections
```

(Use `sudo` for installing radicale although this is not mentioned in the installation advice, because otherwise the program [won't work](https://github.com/Kozea/Radicale/issues/894) as a service with `systemctl`. Also, `sudo pip3 install --upgrade radicale[bcrypt]` might work.)

For encryption of the password-file use

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade radicale[bcrypt]
```

Install `htpasswd` via

```
sudo apt install apache2-utils
```

---

Bind the server to the IP of the Pi, making the WebGUI accessible from outside the Pi with

```
sudo mkdir /etc/radicale
sudo mkdir /home/radicale
sudo nano /etc/radicale/config
```

with content beeing (don't forget to forward the port on the router):

```
[server]
hosts = YOURIP:5232

[auth]
type = htpasswd
htpasswd_filename = /home/radicale/.radicalepasswords
htpasswd_encryption = bcrypt
```

Create a new htpasswd file with credentials for "user1"

```
htpasswd -B -c /home/radicale/.radicalepasswords user1
```

To add another user

```
htpasswd -B /home/radicale/.radicalepasswords user2
```

---

Start `radicale` using a (manually created) configuration file:

```
sudo python3 -m radicale --storage-filesystem-folder=~/.var/lib/radicale/collections
```

Connect to the WebGUI with http://IP:5232. Default username and password both is `admin`. However, since we created a user and set the `config` up with `auth` this is not going to work anymore. Instead we have to log in as the user we created and then create a calendar in the WebGUI.

The WebGUI provides the calendar with IP including the username. This can be used to set up in a client (I tested with macOS).

---

To run it as a system-wide service with `systemd`:

```
sudo useradd --system --home-dir / --shell /sbin/nologin radicale
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/radicale/collections 
sudo chown -R radicale:radicale /var/lib/radicale/collections
sudo chmod -R o= /var/lib/radicale/collections
```

Create the `radicale.service`:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/radicale.service
```

with content beeing:

```
[Unit]
Description=A simple CalDAV (calendar) and CardDAV (contact) server
After=network.target
Requires=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env python3 -m radicale
Restart=on-failure
User=radicale
# Deny other users access to the calendar data
UMask=0027
# Optional security settings
PrivateTmp=true
ProtectSystem=strict
ProtectHome=true
PrivateDevices=true
ProtectKernelTunables=true
ProtectKernelModules=true
ProtectControlGroups=true
NoNewPrivileges=true
ReadWritePaths=/var/lib/radicale/collections

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the service:

```
sudo systemctl enable radicale
sudo systemctl start radicale
sudo systemctl status radicale
```

Logs for errors are in `sudo journalctl --unit radicale.service`.

---

Credits and information:

[radicale](https://radicale.org/2.1.html)

[python3 pip](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md)

[forwarding localhost](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209269/how-to-connect-to-localhost-of-headless-server-for-syncthing)

---

Use `-D` for debugging:
`python3 -m radicale -D --verify-storage --storage-filesystem-folder=~/.var/lib/radicale/collections`

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: `master` now uses `md5` for the password encryption: https://radicale.org/master.html

Comment: `password` file has to go in `/etc/radicale/` if this is where the config is.